# How to represent static variable declaration in flowchart documentation?

Tags: c, flowchart

I'm in the process of documenting some firmware but I'm unsure what the standard is (if there is one) for representing static variable declaration in flowcharts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the 'classic' flowchart it would just be the rectangle.